# Im trying to deploy a spring boot app on heroku im using oracle database in my app

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, maven, heroku

Im using heroku cli to deploy my app 
when i tap the command git push heroku master it gives me

```
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project microoracle-final: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.oraclefinal:microoracle-final:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to heroku-boot-spring.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/heroku-boot-spring.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/heroku-boot-spring.git'`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project microoracle-final: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.oraclefinal:microoracle-final:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

... you are trying to download `ojdbc7` version `12.1.0`, but in Maven Repository there is only `12.1.0.2`. Go to your pom.xml and change the version of ojdbc7 to `12.1.0.2`

Full version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ojdbc7.jar is not able to install from maven repo.

Do following on machine where you're deploying-

1. Download the jar from this [link](http://nexus.saas.hand-china.com/content/repositories/rdc/com/oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar)
2. Execute the jar using following command from terminal

   > mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar
   >   -DgroupId=com.oracle      -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
3. Now try to execute deploy command.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0 isn't in Central. Oracle FINALLY has JDBC driver in Central:

- https://javalibs.com/artifact/com.oracle.ojdbc/ojdbc10
- https://medium.com/oracledevs/oracle-jdbc-drivers-on-maven-central-64fcf724d8b

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
   <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```